# How to achieve horizontal stack of carousel view in jetpack compose android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

Basically i want to achieve carousel view in compose like the below screenshot where it should show 2 views from the left with faded and scaled and one in the center and one from the right with 10% visible

[image]

I tried with HorizontalPager but only one view is visible in the left but i want to achieve with 2 views in the left

Answer (score 0):

A normal carousel effect would use use [`LazyRow`](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/foundation/lazyrow/) in combination with [`HorizontalPager`](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#horizontalpager), which was provided by [Accompanist](https://github.com/google/accompanist/blob/main/pager/README.md), and is now directly in  [`androidx.compose.foundation.pager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/pager/package-summary).

But in your case, there would be by default no z-axis overlapping effect, no fading, no 20% width-visible on the left, 10% on the right!
Only a custom `HorizontalPager` can be used to implement those specifications.

Assuming, for this example, 200px-width images, that would be something like (no fully tested):

```kotlin
@Composable
fun Carousel(images: List<Bitmap>, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()
    val pagerState = rememberPagerState(
        pageCount = images.size,
        initialPage = 0,
        initialPageOffset = 0f
    )

    HorizontalPager(
        state = pagerState,
        modifier = modifier.fillMaxSize(),
        itemSpacing = 10.dp
    ) { page ->
        val currentImage = images[page]
        val offset = (pagerState.currentPage - page) + pagerState.currentPageOffset

        Image(
            bitmap = currentImage.asImageBitmap(),
            contentDescription = null,
            modifier = Modifier
                .graphicsLayer {
                    lerp(
                        start = 0.85f,
                        stop = 1f,
                        fraction = kotlin.math.abs(offset).coerceIn(0f, 1f)
                    ).also { scale ->
                        scaleX = scale
                        scaleY = scale
                    }
                    // Change the alpha of the page depending on its position
                    alpha = lerp(
                        start = 0.5f,
                        stop = 1f,
                        fraction = 1f - kotlin.math.abs(offset)
                    )
                }
                .zIndex(1f - kotlin.math.abs(offset))
        )
    }
}
```

The (non-deprecated)`rememberPagerState(pageCount = images.size)` from the [official Compose paging library](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/foundation/pager/package-summary) is compliant with the migration guide: it now requires a source of truth for `pageCount` as of [Jetpack Compose 1.4.0](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/compose-animation#1.4.0).

Also, the `itemSpacing` parameter in the `HorizontalPager` composable has been renamed to `pageSpacing` as per the migration guide.

Comment: Hi i've tried your code by passing list of bitmap images but its just display blank screen

Comment: @sohanshetty as a way to debug, I would simplify the code first to revert to a [basic HorizontalPager example](https://google.github.io/accompanist/pager/#horizontalpager), and make that work (meaning display images), before adding back the code from above.

Comment: its working with basic horizontalPager example but showing blank screen from the above code.

Comment: I guess its because of 0 -> listOf(null, null) this. for zeroth index we are adding null as item due to which its showing blank screen

Comment: @sohanshetty True. I have updated the code for `HorizontalPager` to handle the null values properly. Null images are handled by not trying to render them.

Comment: Thanks for the quick update i tired your updated code and now your updated code is showing only one view for entire viewport. but i want to achieve like in the screenshot

Comment: @sohanshetty That is frustrating (especially since I do not have the proper testing environment). But that means a Jetpack Compose `HorizontalPager` is not designed to show multiple items at once. You might need combination of other Composables like `LazyRow` and `Box`.

Answer (score -2):

To achieve a horizontal stack of carousel view in Jetpack Compose for Android, you can utilize the `LazyRow` composable along with `carousel` modifier. Here's an example code snippet to help you get started:

```kotlin
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyRow
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.items
import androidx.compose.runtime.Composable
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier

@Composable
fun CarouselView() {
    val carouselItems = listOf(/* Add your list of items here */)

    LazyRow(
        modifier = Modifier.carousel(),
    ) {
        items(carouselItems) { item ->
            // Compose item view
            // Replace `YourItem` with your custom item view composable
            YourItem(item)
        }
    }
}
```

In the example above, `carouselItems` represent the list of items you want to display in the carousel. Replace `YourItem` with your own custom item view composable. Additionally, you can customize the `modifier` parameter of `LazyRow` to add any desired styling or layout modifiers.

Please note that the `carousel` modifier is available starting from Jetpack Compose version `1.0.0-beta09`. Make sure you have the appropriate version in your `build.gradle` file.

I hope this helps you achieve the horizontal stack of carousel view in Jetpack Compose for Android. If you have any further questions, feel free to ask.

Comment: this is not valid answer because im using jetpack compose version 1.2.0 and i dont see carousel modifier in that version